# Is it possible to add solution-specific tools to Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, extensibility

Can you do something to the .SLN/.CSPROJ files in VS2012 so that when you right-click the solution/project in the Solution Explorer, there would be a new item on the context-menu which runs a tool you specify?

I know you can add custom entries to the Tools menu, but in this case the tools are specific to that particular solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can add buttons to `Solution` context menu like below from an Add-In:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars.CommandBar menuBarCommandBar = ((Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars.CommandBars)_applicationObject.CommandBars)["Solution"];

try
{
    //Add a command to the Commands collection:
    Command command = commands.AddNamedCommand2(_addInInstance, "MyAddinMenuBar", "MyAddinMenuBar", "Executes the command for MyAddinMenuBar", true, 59, ref contextGUIDS, (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusSupported + (int)vsCommandStatus.vsCommandStatusEnabled, (int)vsCommandStyle.vsCommandStylePictAndText, vsCommandControlType.vsCommandControlTypeButton);

    //Add a control for the command to the solution context menu:
    if (command != null)
    {
        command.AddControl(menuBarCommandBar, 1);
    }
}
catch (System.ArgumentException)
{
    //  safely ignore the exception.
}
```

The specification of tools for different solutions should be handled internally by your Add-In. You can extract the full path of a solution (from `_applicationObject.Solution.FullName`) also the properties of contained projects (from  `_applicationObject.Solution.Projects` ).

If you are using a `VSPackage` you should define a `vsct` file to add the command and the menu item.

Comment: Can I add an add-in to the solution? That is, put it in the source control, so that whoever checks out a copy and opens the solution, also gets the add-in automatically installed?

Comment: If you place the source code into your solution, then I think your Add-In won't be deployed properly. You have to copy the .AddIn file to ..\Documents\Visual Studio 20[XY]\Addins folder, and set the <Assembly> element to make it work. There is shared .AddIn container also, but then the assemly have to be placed on a global path.

Comment: For deployment I advice to use WiX Toolset (available as online Extension) and you can also try to use your Add-In as a [Solution Add-In](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165621.aspx).